# arranging pairs of rows in to single row

Tags: awk

I have a text file like this.

```
4IGL    A   1488
4IGL    B   690
4IU2    A   212
4IU2    B   243
4IYP    B   222
4IYP    C   151
```

I would like to arrange the pairs of rows in to single row. How can I do this with awk?

Desired output

```
4IGL    A   1488    B   690
4IU2    A   212     B   243
4IYP    B   222     C   151
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
awk 'NR%2==1 {line=$0; next} {printf("%-20s%-4s%s\n", line, $2, $3)}' file
```

This assumes that the lines appear in pairs with the same first field, as you've shown, and that there are no blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
 sed -n 'N;s/\r*\n[^ ]* / /p' input
```

*Gives:*

```
4IGL    A   1488   B   690
4IU2    A   212   B   243
4IYP    B   222   C   151
```

You can add a column command for better looks:

```
 sed -n 'N;s/\r*\n[^ ]* / /p' input | column -t
```

*Producing:*

```
4IGL  A  1488  B  690
4IU2  A  212   B  243
4IYP  B  222   C  151
```